# Can applying pressure to joints provide some health benefits?

Tags: immune-system

My question goes beyond the obvious wisdom of not being sedentary. I was told by someone, with a fair amount of medical training, of the benefits of applying pressure to the joints and connective tissue. Specifically, that a sit-to-stand adapter, by bracing the knees would somehow boost the immune system. I am inclined to defer to his greater knowledge, yet I couldn't find supporting evidence or information from "Dr. Google."

Comment: Proving a negative (that something has no effect) is pretty hard, especially something like this where I doubt any scientific studies have been done. Besides, "boosting the immune system" is something that gets said a lot, but has no meaningful definition. Can you think of anything you would accept as proof that this association does not exist?

Comment: He stated "lots of people know this", implying that studies had been done and were known to a larger community. I believe in seeking independent verification, when practical, for what I believe AND disbelieve. I was fairly certain that what he said was BS, but sought out an objective opinion. I agree with you that a lack of evidence is not in itself evidence that there isn't any evidence. If his claim could have been substantiated in any way I would have lent it more credibility. Thank you for your reply.